# Django URL tag: Getting a NoReverseMatch on model id even though it exists

Tags: django, templates, variables, url

Really tiring issue today with Django templates. I've been successfully using URL tags with no issues for a while until today. I can't figure it out for the life of me. In the code below If I do a really ugly way of storing the url as a variable and then put it in an `<a>` element, I get no problems and it works as normal.

```
{% url 'app:post' post_id=recentpost.id as the_url %}
<a href="{{ the_url }}">I'm linking to {{recentpost.id }} {{the_url}}</a>
```

Rendered Output of above:

```
<a href="/post/18/">I'm linking to 18 /post/18/</a>
```

(I did it this way to debug what was going on--I've never had to store the url as a variable and then insert it into an `<a>` before.)

Now if I do it normally in a single template tag--I get a NoReverseMatch Error:

```
<a href="{% url 'app:post' post_id=recentpost.id %}">TEST</a>

django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'post' with keyword arguments '{'post_id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post\\\\/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)\\\\/$']
```

What's irritating, is that there is an identical `{% url %}` tag further down the template resolving the same URL but with a different post model ID, the only difference is that the variable name is "post" rather than "recentpost"

It appears in the Exception that it's passing an empty variable to 'post_id' -- or that recentpost.id = ""   -- If I just print the variable the id number shows up fine or if I store it as a variable first--it works fine.

I'm at a loss. Haaaaaaalp!

EDIT:

```
{# This doesn't work either with same error #}
{% url 'app:post' recentpost.id %}
```

Url path:

```
path('post/<int:post_id>/', views.post, name='post')
```

I'm using the same context variable immediately after the `<a>` tag and accessing variables successfully.

Here's the views.py:

```
def post(request, **kwargs):
    blogpost = BlogPost.objects.get(pk=kwargs['post_id'])
    #Make sure we don't populate our lists below with the current requested post
    blogposts = BlogPost.objects.filter(project=None).exclude(id=kwargs['post_id']).order_by('-date_created') 
    recentposts = BlogPost.objects.exclude(id=kwargs['post_id']).order_by('-date_created')[:5]
    blogposts = blogposts[0:10]
    kwargs.update({'blogpost':blogpost})
    kwargs.update({'blogpost_list':blogposts}) 
    kwargs.update({'recentposts_list':recentposts})     
    return HttpResponse(render_to_response('public_frontend/blogpost.html', kwargs, RequestContext(request)))  

def dev_index(request, **kwargs):
    blogposts = BlogPost.objects.filter(project=None).order_by('-date_created') 
    recentpost = blogposts[0]
    blogposts = blogposts[1:10]
    kwargs.update({'recentpost':recentpost})
    kwargs.update({'blogpost_list':blogposts}) 
    return HttpResponse(render_to_response('public_frontend/dev_index.html', kwargs, RequestContext(request)))
```

`dev_index` is the view that goes to the template with the error.

`blog` view has zero issues when an int ID is passed as an argument and works as normal

This is the problem I've narrowed:

`Reverse for 'post' with keyword arguments '{'post_id': ''}' not found`

recentpost.id is coming up as a blank variable--when it's not.

Works here=> `{% url 'app:post' post_id=recentpost.id as the_url %}`

Doesn't work here=>`{% url 'app:post' post_id=recentpost.id %}`

## =============================================================================

RECENT EDITS:

If I surround the same tag in an arbitrary for loop--it works as expected.

```
{{recentpost}}  <!-- prints "BlogPost Object (15)"
{{recentpost.id}}   <!-- prints 15
{% for test in recentpost.name %}
    <a href="{% url 'app:post' post_id=recentpost.id %}"></a>
{% endfor %}

Output: <a href="/post/15/"></a>   (*n) number of characters in title
```

Also I get the exact same error for both these:

```
{% url 'app:post' post_id='' %}
{% url 'app:post' post_id=recentpost.id %}
```

And when placing it in a `with` block:

```
{{recentpost}} <!-- prints "BlogPost Object (15)"
{{recentpost.id}} <!-- prints 15

{% with test=recentpost%}
    <a href="{% url 'app:post' post_id=test.id %}"></a>
{% endwith %}

Output: NoReverseMatch Error -- Reverse for 'post' with keyword arguments '{'post_id': ''}' not found.
```

Also works if placed between an `if` tag:

```
{% if recentpost%} <a href="{% url 'app:post' post_id=recentpost.id %}"></a>{% endif %} <!-- Works with no error and returns proper url

<a href="{% url 'app:post' post_id=recentpost.id %}"></a> <!-- Does not work and returns a NoReverseMatch 404 because the `recentpost` variable is `None`
```

It's an accurate Error--it will return a 404 error or NoReverseMatch for the url `/post/` --it will only return a url if it's `/post/15/` -- or any integer.

The issue seems to be with the context variable `recentpost`  It works in a `{{recentpost}}` print --but as soon as I use it in the url tag, it's `None`--as if the template hasn't loaded the Object in time to use it in an  URL tag.

ADDITIONAL EVIDENCE:

```
<a href="{% url 'app:post' post_id=recentpost|default:'NONE' %}"></a>
Output: NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'post' with keyword arguments '{'post_id': 'NONE'}' not found.
```

This is an expected error because `/post/NONE/` will return a 404 error

The actual object is None or Null and defaults to a blank space--if I override the default with `|default='NONE'`   we can see the problem is the variable not existing in the context within that URL tag

I also tried passing a context variable `test_post='15'` to the template from the view and have the exact same issue.

```
{{test_post}}  <!-- output in template is 15
```

but

```
{% url 'app:post' post_id=test_post|default='NONE' %}
Output: NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'post' with keyword arguments '{'post_id': 'NONE'}' not found.
```

Variable is definitely being passed to the template--much like the others but when --ANY-- variable is pushed into a `{%url%}` tag without being in a `for` or `if` block, it's `None` e.g. even if I do:

```
{% url 'app:post' post_id=blogposts.0.id %} it's None
```

but in `blogposts`'s `For` loop, the items are not `None` and the `{%url%}` tag's work fine with that loop block.

Comment: Did you try: `{% url 'app:post' recentpost.id %}`?

Comment: Yep. Same problem. the url is:

`path('post/<int:post_id>/', views.post, name='post') `

The issues seems to be that inside that tag, the recentpost.id is coming up as null or blank. The url path is looking for an INT so when it receives a blank/null variable it can't resolve a url

Comment: It looks to me that there is no named group `post_id` in the url regex. Could you please post your `urls.py`?

Comment: Maybe you did not send any `recentpost` variable via context from your view

Comment: `recentpost` is in the context--I use the variable to print other variables from the model without issue.

Comment: or may be your view does not take additional argument? `def some(request, id)`?

Comment: the view works fine--everything works fine. If I resolve the URL to a variable and then add it to an <a> tag I have zero issues.

It's when I try and resolve it straight to an <a> tag without being stored as a variable first

Comment: When you store it in a variable like you said, what is the rendering/output of that `I'm linking to {{recentpost.id }} {{the_url}}`

Comment: The Output is:
`<a href="/blog/18/">I'm linking to 18 /blog/18/</a>`
  This is correct and works as expected.

I can also access `recentpost` 's other variables with no issues--it's ONLY when I try and directly access the id or pk within the `{% url %}` tag.     It's driving me crazy because I'm using several identical  `{% url %}` tags after that resolve just fine--the only difference in variable name

Comment: You updated your answer, add your view as well

Comment: Updated it--the views are working as they should.

Comment: `**kwargs` - but this is "named argument", dictionary, u have to use `*args` instead.

Comment: @Chiefir -- if that's the case why does it work fine here: `{% url 'app:post' post_id=recentpost.id as the_url %}`  with no issue

Comment: About to leave work but I'll check in later. Thanks for the help so far everyone

Comment: looks like it is cuz u are actualy **naming** - { "post_id": 18 } . To check this theory - just rename to `post_id_test` - if it will be still working in your *template*.

Comment: I bet this is the error what I was talking on the beginning - wrong view definition.

Comment: @Chiefer I get the same `noReverseMatch` error after renaming to `post_id_test` .    If `{% url 'app:post' post_id=recentpost.id as the_url %}` works fine in the template, and calling the same url/view with a different context post object works perfectly fine with the exact same syntax--I can't see it as a naming issue.

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't wrap the result of `render_to_response` in `HttpResponse`. Also, `render_to_response` is obsolete. Use `render` instead, e.g. `return render(request, 'public_frontend/dev_index.html', kwargs)`.

Comment: What happens if you define `kwargs` as `kwargs = {'recentpost': recentpost, 'blogpost_list': blogpost_list}`. I can't think why that would make a difference, but that part of your view does look unusual.

Comment: @Alasdair -- no changes. I agree it looks unusual lol though--it's older code. I did update the question with another case-example.

I can just surround it in an `if` tag and call it a day--but this is the only template I'm having this issue on--I have about 30 others that have no issues using this exact same url/view/ `{%url%}` syntax.  The only difference between this specific template and the others--they all inherit a base template, and this one does not inherit a base template.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have any other suggestions. If `{% url 'app:post' post_id=recentpost.id as the_url %}` works, then `{% url 'app:post' post_id=recentpost.id %}` should work as well. I've pointed out a few things in the view you should fix up, but I don't see anything that would explain the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: @Alasdair honestly about to put this in as a bug on the Django forums. I can't think of why it's happening. Today I'm just gonna have to surround it with an `if` tag and move on unless some magical solution pops up here I dunno. Variable is definitely being passed to the template--much like the others but when any variable is pushed into a `{%url%}` tag without being in a `for` or `if` block, it's `None`  e.g. even if I do: `{% url 'app:post' post_id=blogposts.0.id %}`  it's `None`  but in `blogposts` 's `For` loop, the items are not `None` and the `{%url%}` tag's work fine.

Comment: If you open a bug report, I would try to produce a simple example that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Which version of django were you using? I have always the same problem and I'm thinking maybe is the django version. Maybe they fix it.